# How to add new line after JTextField in each iteration of loop?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, newline, jtextfield

I have to display a map containing two columns and the size is dynamic. I am currently displaying it in a panel, but the problem is I cannot start each row of the map in the new line, rather it depends on the frame size of the display. Here is the full code:

```
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;

    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Image;

    public class P05  {
        private JLabel label;
        private JLabel label1;
        private JLabel label3;
        private JTextField tf;
        private JPanel panel;

    public P05() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Search result and score");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);

        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
        label = new JLabel("Search Result:                             ");
        label1 = new JLabel();
        label3 = new JLabel("Score:  ");
        tf=new JTextField(10);
        tf.setBounds(10,10, 150,20);

        JButton button = new JButton("Search");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String text = tf.getText();
                label1.setText("The input query is " + text);
        
                panel.removeAll();
                panel.add(label);
                panel.add(label3);

                int i = 0;
                Map < String, Double> map = new HashMap < String, Double> ();
                 map.put("Jennifer Anniston", 31.0);
                 map.put("brad_pit", 29.0);
                 map.put("Angelina Jolie", 30.0);
                 map.put("badley", 21.0);
                 map.put("Leonardo Decaprio", 43.0);
                 map.put("Kate Winslet", 41.0);
                 map.put("Julia Roberts", 40.0);
                 map.put("Emma Watson", 34.0);
                 map.put("Mayim Bialik", 28.0);
                 map.put("Cobie Smulders", 28.0);
         
                 for(String item:map.keySet()) {
                     JTextField t1[] = new JTextField[12];
                     t1[i] = new JTextField(20);
                     t1[i].setText(item );
                     panel.add(t1[i]);
             
                     JTextField t2[] = new JTextField[12];
                     t2[i] = new JTextField(5);
                     t2[i].setText(Double.toString(map.get(item)));
                     panel.add(t2[i]);
                     i++;
                }
                 panel.add(label1);
                 panel.revalidate();
            }
        });

        buttonPane.add(tf);
        buttonPane.add(button);

        panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(panel); 
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new P05();
        }
```

The output looks like somewhat this:

[image]

The quick and dirty solution right now is for me to set the frame size of lower width and it will come in a new line, but in that case, if the text field contains a value with many characters it will not show the whole text. So need a solution to add a new line after each row.

Comment: Use a JList or JTable, it’s what they’re designed for

Comment: Alternatively, use a GridBagLayout or GridLayout with compound components

Comment: Refer to [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). And after that have a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)